# How to reset(?) a (out-of-sync)DB on a MySQL master-master replication

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I have a master-master MySQL replication. It was delicious until yesterday but, for some reason which I could not figure it out yet, they lost synchronization. I've been wandering around forums and several tools, tips and advices but it seems like I cannot not figure it out myself in time.

So I have the idea just to reset the problematic DB. If I am not imagining wrong, I was planning to dump all the data from the (out-of-sync)DB and then re-attach it to the other master as if I am adding a brand new slave.

Of course I am worried about the NON-problematic master. (the other one basically). When I dump everything from the problematic (out-of-sync)DB, it should not also dump everything as being a slave at the same time.

I hope I made myself clear. I tried to be as clear and short as I can. I can always provide more information if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I happened to wrote a short [blog post](http://www.celalo.com/how-to-fix-re-sync-mysql-master-master-replic) about how to overcome this ages later.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look into Maakit's tools?

[Mk-Table-Sync](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-table-sync.html) should be able to help you out.